Can Mockito actually mock the deep inner function return?
My code is somewhat "modular", each module is reused by many other modules.
So, I want to test the process():
public class ServiceImpl {

    SomeSM someSM;

    @Autowired
    public void setSomeSM(SomeSM someSM) {
        this.someSM = someSM;
    }

    @Override
    public Map process(Map requestBody) throws Exception {
        Map params01 = new HashMap();
        Map params02 = new HashMap();

        // Compile body to params in some lines here

        Map rawResultProcess01 = someSM.callThirdPartyProcess01(params01);
        Map rawResultProcess02 = someSM.callThirdPartyProcess02(params02);

        Map finalResult = new HashMap();

        // Compile rawResult to finalResult in some lines here

        return finalResult;
    }

}

Then here's SomeSMImpl:
@Service
public class SomeSMImpl implements SomeSM {

    @Override
    public Map callThirdPartyProcess01(Map payload) throws Exception {
        Map rawResult = new HashMap();
        HttpRequestHelper httpHelper = new HttpRequestHelper();
        Map parsedJson = httpHelper.postHTTPS(payload.get("headers"), payload.get("body"), payload.get("params"), Map.class);

        if(parsedJson.get("api_code") != null)
        // ........ some processes here


        return rawResult;
    }

    @Override
    public Map callThirdPartyProcess02(Map payload) throws Exception {
        Map rawResult = new HashMap();
        HttpRequestHelper httpHelper = new HttpRequestHelper();
        Map parsedJson = httpHelper.postHTTPS(payload.get("headers"), payload.get("body"), payload.get("params"), Map.class);

        if(parsedJson.get("api_code") != null)
        // ........ some processes here


        return rawResult;
    }
}

The 2 APIs return different values, and that's what I want to mock, because I want to ensure the behavior of processing data on my end keep the same every auto test goes, unless there's changes. Also, there's some mappings / process from processedJson to rawResult
How can I mock the parsedJson's values on the 2 SomeSM methods when testing from the ServiceImpl class?

Why do you even want to mock parsedJson from process? process() does not really care about that, it cares and uses the returned maps, you should mock callThirdPartyProcessN().

@Chaosfire Well, there is some processes here that do some early checks on it and remap. I would like to ensure how the service processes regarding the results gotten from the third party processes. So I'd mock the parsedJson with the converted original JSON output of them.
